# How to use classified styles with joined layers?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, mapping

I am trying to [set a color range based on this tutorial](http://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/tutorials/qgis-basics-journalists/choropleth/)

In LAYER PROPERTIES for "new", in JOINS, I have
joinlayer - data-join
joinfield - GEO_ID2
targetfield - GEOID10

Where "new" is my shapefile and "data-join" is my DBF file with the data I want to use for the graduated color. I want to join column "geo_id2" in "data-join" with "geoID10" in "new."

After I am set up, I click "Apply," then "OK."

When I toggle over to Style, I see the column I wish to use --- "total-hous" I have selected a color ramp "blues" and 5 classes at equal intervals.

But I'm not getting a range like in the Knight example, just five categories all with a range from 0 to 0.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that's a known bug.

You can export the joined layer to a new Shapefile using "Save as ...". Then load it again and the classification will work.